# Get publication ID of publication from where page is getting published

Tags: event-system

I need to find publication ID of publication from where page is getting saved through event system page save event.
I tried to get publication ID through owning/context publication property but not able to get the correct publication ID and both are give publication id where we have created page i.e Masterwebsite

All page are created at 050 level but editing a page from 080 level, while trying to get publication ID through owning/context publication its giving same 050 level publicatin ID. But for our case we need to get publication ID of 080 level if this is not possible through these properties then how to achieve this.

Thanks
Nash

Comment: My page is localized at 080 level, its at 050 level only but I am saving page from 080 level.

Answer (score 4):

Just do:

```
var pubId = Page.Id.ContextRepositoryId
```

or

```
var pubId = Page.Id.PublicationId
```

and then:

```
var publicationId = new TcmUri(pubId, ItemType.Publication);
```

This is the lightest method as you already have publication Id in TcmUri of page, for example your page id is: `tcm:5-6-64`. The publication Id will be: `tcm:0-5-1`. So `TcmUri` class helps you get advantage of this without even talking to Tridion server.

Comment: Page.ContextRepository.Id should also give the same TCM URI

Answer (score 1):

Is your page localized at the 080 level?

Unless the page has been localized it is still edited and saved at the parent level regardless of where it was opened from.